# Add dentro de um array nova posição no javascript

Tags: javascript, lista, arraylist, controller

```
var produtos = new Array();

produtos = [{"Id":2,"Nome":"X bacon","Valor":12,"Quantidade":1},{"Id":3,"Nome":"Lucas","Valor":9.97,"Quantidade":1},{"Id":4,"Nome":"teste","Valor":5,"Quantidade":1}]
```

Estou enviando para Controlle e retornando um data, com novos atributos

```
produtos = [{"Id":2,"Nome":"X bacon","Valor":12,"Quantidade":1, "Imagem": xxxx, "Descricao": yyy},{"Id":3,"Nome":"Lucas","Valor":9.97,"Quantidade":1 "Imagem": xxxx, "Descricao": yyy},},{"Id":4,"Nome":"teste","Valor":5,"Quantidade":1 "Imagem": xxxx, "Descricao": yyy},}]
```

só que quando pego meu data todos atributos ficam minusculo,

```
Id -> id...
```

como faço pra pegar somente a imagem e descrição do data e concatenar no produto.
tentei isso:

```
$(data).each(function (i) {
                produtos[i] = produtos.concat(data[i].imagem);

});
```

data:
http://prntscr.com/mci2na

produtos:
http://prntscr.com/mci3sl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se trata de um objeto em JavaScript e não simplesmente um array.

Se eu entendi bem você quer adicionar os elementos Imagem e Descrição sem alterar a capitalização dos atributos.

Tente o seguinte em JS puro:

```
produtos = [
  {"Id":2,"Nome":"X bacon","Valor": 12,"Quantidade":1},
  {"Id":3,"Nome":"Lucas","Valor":9.97,"Quantidade":1},
  {"Id":4,"Nome":"teste","Valor":5,"Quantidade":1}
];

produtos.forEach(function (produto) { 
    produto["Imagem"] = "imagem.jpg";
    produto["Descricao"] = "Descricao do produto";
});

// Debugging only
document.write(JSON.stringify(produtos));
```

Link para o JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/86kan9xp/7/

Comment: Obrigado "La Flame", conseguir resolver seguindo sua lógica Fiz isso:

success: function (data) {
            produtos.forEach(function (produto, i) {
                produto["Imagem"] = data[i].imagem;
                produto["Descricao"] = data[i].descricao;
            });            
            setCookie();
        },